# Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION QuickBlox chat jar

Tags: java, android, gradle, quickblox

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

```
com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/androidannotations;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:592)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:550)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:531)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

Gradle dependecy:

```
compile 'jars/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.2.1.jar'
```

Note: I also use android-support-v4 dependency.

From my understanding error seems like android.support.annotations exists in
both 'quickblox chat' & 'android support'.

So, is there any way I can exclude 'android.support.annotations' package from quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.2.1.jar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in a latest commit today https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/commit/d326b402a6bbb8517434489873c4d2a8b2688e51